# What may cause huge load in Kafka `__consumer_offsets` topic?

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, load, internal, consumer

I have simple observation in my Kafka cluster (Kafka 0.11.0.0).

According to jmx information the `__consumer_offsets` topic constantly is loaded with 10 times more messages than sum of all messages in all other topics.
I had also conected console consumer to this topic and I can measure similar values.

- What could be the reason?
- How can I check what is Kafka broker doing and generate such a load on its own?

Comment: if you read __cosumer_offsets topic, you can know what groupId do load. That should help in research

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But unfortunately messages in this topic are binary and I do not see anything :-(.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to read __consumer_offsets topic:

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic __consumer_offsets --bootstrap-server brokers --formatter "kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter" --new-consumer --consumer.config consumer.conf`

for kafka 11 use formatter `"kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter"`

where consumer.conf has one line

`exclude.internal.topics=false`

Comment: --formatter "kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter" --new-consumer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager$OffsetsMessageFormatter
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
      at ...
      at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsoleConsumer.scala:318)
      at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:51)
      at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)

Comment: kafka_2.12-0.11.0.1

Comment: yep. works for 9 and 10. I'll look for solution in 11

Comment: try kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter

Comment: One more comment. We found what was causing this huge load. 
Flink by defaut makes cluster/client synch every 10ms! It is perhaps good default for flink, but this may devastate broker performance.

Answer (score 1):

For version 2.2  of kafka, this is a demo:

**kafka_2.12-2.2.1**/bin #

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server  your-broker   --topic __consumer_offsets --formatter  "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter"
```

Output will be:

```
[MyGroup-7cc5f948df-f9tqz,__MY_TOPIC,2]::OffsetAndMetadata(offset=30, leaderEpoch=Optional.empty, metadata=, commitTimestamp=1568121107017, expireTimestamp=None)
```

Comment: I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter`. Do you know how to fix it? I am using kafka_2.12-2.3.0.